# Laravel framework like package, dump-autoload not working

Tags: laravel, package, composer-php

For a project I'm working on I would like to create a 'Core' package containing multiple smaller packages, like laravel does with it's framework.
The folder structure would be something like this,

```
Package1: gybrus/core/src/Gybrus/Package1
Package2: gybrus/core/src/Gybrus/Package1
```

After doing some research I've noticed this could be achieved with composer if I'm not mistaken but this is also where it breaks for me.
Currently I have multiple composer.json files, but after running the 'php artisan dump-autoload' command the classes aren't added to the autoload files.
Therefore I'm wondering if the Laravel framework adds some extra magic to make this happen.

Thanks in advance!

This is my current setup, I've changed the package names for the sake of not advertising something ;)
The first composer file is in the 'core' folder next to the 'src' folder.

```
{
  "name": "gybrus/core",
  "description": "The Core",
  "keywords": ["core"],
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "Kevin Dierkx",
      "email": "email@email.com"
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.0",
    "laravel/framework": "4.0.x"
  },
  "replace": {
    "gybrus/package1": "self.version"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "mockery/mockery": "dev-master",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.*"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
      "Gybrus": "src/"
    }
  },
  "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

The second composer file is in the package1 folder:

```
{
    "name": "gybrus/package1",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Gybrus",
            "email": "email@email.com"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.0",
        "illuminate/support": "4.0.x"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {"Gybrus\\Package1": ""}
    },
    "target-dir": "Gybrus/Package1",
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

Comment: Er - you have multiple composer files in one package?

Comment: Yes I do, this package contains multiple smaller packages. The laravel framework does something similar, the problem with this is that I don't get it to work like the laravel framework does.

Answer (score 0):

Found the cause of my problem!

The first script tells composer that it should autoload the namespace 'Gybrus' starting in the 'src' folder, after some testing this works as intended.
Where the above setup breaks is the following line:

```
return Finder::create()->files()->in($workbench)->name('composer.json')->depth('< 3');
```

This tells the Finder to stop looking for composer.json files that are deeper than 2 folders.
Nothing weird so far.

Where is goes wrong is here, I symlinked the workbench packages into the workbench folder.
This causes the weird problem that the composer.json files are actually deeper than they should be, which in result stop the loading of the composer.json files and breaking the autoloading for these packages.

A quick fix would be to either don't symlink or run composer install from inside the package.